# EDSDK flashlight control

Tags: c#, edsdk

did anybody succeed in controlling a flashlight connected to an EOS through Canon's c# wrapper? I'd like to modify the exposure compensation for example or check whether the flashlight has reloaded and is ready to fire. I tried 
EDSDK.PropID_FlashCompensation 
or 
EDSDK.PropID_FlashOn 
within the  Camera_SDKPropertyEvent callback, but in case you switch on the Speedlite no callback fires. Using the cameras menu manually (External flash funk. setting) all works fine. Seems that it is not possible to do that programmatically using EDSDK?
I am greatful for any hint or suggestion. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At this point (V3.2) flash control is very limited with the Canon SDK and I'm afraid you won't be able to do anything meaningful.

PropID_FlashCompensation is a read-only property and from the documentation:

> Note that flash compensation cannot be retrieved for an external flash.

PropID_FlashOn is not a camera property, but an image property. (i.e. reading metadata from a locally saved image)
Same goes for PropID_FlashMode.

Note that this not usable anymore since version 3.2, as image support has been dropped.