# Can Canon EDSDK be used to crontrol internal/external flash?

Tags: c#, edsdk, canon-sdk

I'm using Canon EOS SDK version V13.14.40 with a Canon EOS 700D camera. I have a C# desktop application that I use for live view and image capture. Both live view and image capture works fine. I need to be able to turn on the flash from the computer.

The sdk documentation lists two properties that appear interesting, *EdsPropID_FlashOn* and *kEdsPropID_FlashMode*. However, both of the properties are listed as 'read only' and are apparently only available on an image after the image have been taken.

Apparently it wasn't possible to control the flash with the Canon SDK in the past either, according to [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483679/edsdk-flashlight-control)

Is it at all possible to control an internal or external flash using the Canon EOS SDK?